# How to check and delete pandas column if all rows contain just punctuation character?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I want to delete such columns where all rows **just** contain any of the punctuation character. e-g

```
    col_1 col_2 col_3  col_4
0      1     _    ab    1,235
1      2     ?    cd    8,900
2      3     _    ef    1,235
3      4     -    gh    8,900
```

Here I just want to delete col_2. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is test if all values of column contains number or string by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\d|\w')).all()]
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\d|[a-zA-Z]')).all()]
```

---

```
print (df)
   col_1 col_3  col_4
0      1    ab  1,235
1      2    cd  8,900
2      3    ef  1,235
3      4    gh  8,900
```

If possible get all values for remove in string is posible add `^` for start of string and `$` for end of string and then invert mask by `~`:

```
p = """[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ]"""
df = df.loc[:, ~df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('^' + p + '$')).all()]
print (df)
   col_1 col_3  col_4
0      1    ab  1,235
1      2    cd  8,900
2      3    ef  1,235
3      4    gh  8,900
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use python's string [punctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) method and filter out the column that has punctuations with pandas' [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) method :

```
    import string

    #create a list of individual punctuations
    punctuation_list = list(string.punctuation)

    #filter out unwanted column
    df.loc[:,~df.isin(punctuation_list).all()]

    col_1   col_3   col_4
0      1      ab    1,235
1      2      cd    8,900
2      3      ef    1,235
3      4      gh    8,900
```